# Canvas speechbubble created in Javascript -> measureText height?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm currently trying to create a **speechbubble** for my `canvas` using `javascript`.

**Problem 1:**

I'm adding the width in the following way: `ctx.measureText(text).width + 40` to make sure the width of the speechbubble is flexible and depends on the `var text = 'Speechbubble test';` input. Also adding 40 pixels to add a margin left and right!

How could I get the height of the text to make it flexible also? I've been checking but couldn't find something similare to the `measureText` method and it doesn't seem to exist.

Is there any way to get the actual height of the text? I'm asking because I'm planning to add a line break to it. eG: multi-line support (Break the text line after a specific amount of letters).

**Problem 2:**

I'm trying to add a little speech bubble direction pointer to the speechbubble. Sorry for the way I'm describing it this way, don't know the word for it. But I'm talking about the following:

[image: Image to preview what I'm talking about]

How could I add the following to my speechbubble?

I appreciate any sugestions and help.

**The current example:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "13px Helvetica";
var text = 'Speechbubble test';
component(ctx, ctx.measureText(text).width, 70, "#37f", 10, 10, 16, text);

function component(ctx, width, height, color, x, y, radius, text)
{
   // Variables
   var width = width + 40;
   var height = height;
   var x = x;
   var y = y;
   var radius = Math.min(radius, Math.min(width, height) / 2);
   var color = color;
   var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
   var r = radius;
   var w = width;
   var h = height;
   
   // Transparent background
   //ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
 
   // Draw arc
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(r  , r  , r, pi2 * 0.5 , pi2 * 0.75);
   ctx.arc(w - r, r, r, pi2 * 0.75, pi2);
   ctx.arc(w - r, h - r, r, 0, pi2 * 0.25);
   ctx.arc(r  , h - r, r, pi2 * 0.25, pi2 * 0.5);
   ctx.fill();

   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

   // Text fillstyle
   ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
   ctx.fillText(text, x + 20, y + 40);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although the [specs defines](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#textmetrics) a way to measure height via a the `TextMetrics` object, no vendor has actually implemented it at current time.

So we have to cheat a bit to get the actual size from the font.

One way to do this is to temporary insert a DOM element and get the height from that:

```js
console.log(getTextHeight("Hello", "20px sans-serif"));

function getTextHeight(txt, font) {
  var el = document.createElement('div'), height;
  el.style.cssText = "position:fixed;padding:0;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;font:" + font;
  el.textContent = txt;

  document.body.appendChild(el); 
  height = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  document.body.removeChild(el);
  
  return height
}
```

For use with canvas just pass in `context.font` as your font argument:

```
var fontHeight = getTextHeight("Hello", ctx.font);
```

**As to problem two:**

You can break up the bottom line path so to speak, of the rounded rectangle by inserting `lineTo()` calls, like:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), r = 20, w = 290, h = 100, pi2 = Math.PI*2;
var ap = w * 0.2, aw = 20, ah = 30;  //arrow position, width, height
ctx.translate(1.5,0.5);

// Rounded rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(r  , r  , r, pi2 * 0.5 , pi2 * 0.75);
ctx.arc(w - r, r, r, pi2 * 0.75, pi2);
ctx.arc(w - r, h - r, r, 0, pi2 * 0.25);       // bottom right corner

ctx.lineTo(w - ap, h);                         // inserts an arrow (following clock-wise)
ctx.lineTo(w - ap, h + ah);
ctx.lineTo(w - ap - aw, h);

ctx.arc(r  , h - r, r, pi2 * 0.25, pi2 * 0.5); // bottom left corner
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it!